# git: checkout or clone multiple subsets of a repo

Tags: git

I have 3 places A, B, and C where I want to checkout/clone different, possibly intersecting, subsets of repo R. I would prefer that whatever means is used to "mark" these subsets is a permanent part of the repo (rather than an external list I maintain).

Is this possible, and if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you clone a repo, you will get all content of it, you can't pull only a part of it.

In git, you can use branches to give a name to a commit. So you might start a new branch, compose it the way you want. Afterwards, you push that to the remote repository. Same with B and C.

When you first clone the repo, just select the respective branch you want to use. When you add commits to a branch, the HEAD of the branch will move with the commits, so you will always have the latest version once pushed.

If you look for a single, permanent mark, you can compose your branch, and use a tag. A tag is always associated with a single commit and won't move unless explicitly done by the user.

Comment: So there's no way to avoid N commits for N branches, if they have common files? That's kind of painful.

Comment: No, there isn't. You'll always get the full history. If you want that behaviour, make different repositories and merge between them instead of only one repository.